# running reqMktData with IBpy came across "chr() arg not in range(256)"

Tags: ibpy

Firstly, I use Python2.7, my OS is win7, and my IBpy package is the newest, downloaded from github.

I run example_opt.py, which is an demo from IBpy, then I came across following problem:

```
Server Version: 76
TWS Time at connection:20160326 10:39:29 CST
<managedAccounts accountsList=DU228380>
<nextValidId orderId=1>
<error id=None, errorCode=None, errorMsg=chr() arg not in range(256)>
<connectionClosed>
DISCONNECTED
```

And the example code is the following:

```
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
import time

def watcher(msg):
    print msg

con = ibConnection(port=7497, clientId=888)
con.registerAll(watcher)
con.connect()

contract = Contract()
contract.m_symbol = "EUR"
contract.m_exchange = "IDEALPRO"
contract.m_currency = "USD"
contract.m_secType = "CASH"

con.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False)

time.sleep(5)

con.disconnect()
print "DISCONNECTED"

time.sleep(60)
```

Could somebody help me solve this problem? I think it may be a bug of the latest version because I find somebody else also asked the problem in github.

Many Thanks. Waiting for your answer online!

Comment: Can you try with python 3?  You're getting a python error.  Error messages from IB could just be informational.

Comment: I was asked to use python2.7.

Comment: The code works ok in python 3.  For some reason you get a character that 2.7 can't understand in a error message.  The error messages are often just connection information and not really errors.  You only have 5 seconds to wait for data before you disconnect, try it today when the market is actually open.  The last sleep(60) is useless.

Comment: I tried a older version, which was sent to me by my friend. It works out okay.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the language of your IB app. In my case, I had IB's language set in "Spanish" and I was getting this error on IbPy continuously; then, I changed language to "English" and I could connect to TWS.

Comment: +1 Similar errror with italian language. <error id=None, errorCode=None, errorMsg=chr() arg not in range(0x110000)>
Fixed setting up English language in TWS.